# Is there an easier way to display an array of numbers in a specific base in python?

Tags: python, arrays

To print an array of numbers in a specific base, I've used the following:

```py
print( str(
    [ '{:02x}'.format(array[i])
      for i in range(0, len(array))
    ]
).replace("'", "") ) )
```

Which converts the array of numbers to an array of string representations of the numbers in the base (in this case hex values of 2 digits), and then converts that array into a string and removes the single quotes.

I guess I could also make a function that generates the output in that or some other way.  Perhaps like:

```py
def numbers_as_base(array, base, digits, leading_zeros):
  s = '['
  if len(array) > 0:
    fmt = f'{{:{0 if leading_zeros else ""}{digits}{base}}}'
    for i in range(0, len(array)-1):
      s += fmt.format(array[i]) + ', '
    s += fmt.format(array[-1])
  return s + ']'
```

I was just wondering, is there something in the language/standard library that was already available that would do this for me?  Also, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: can you include sample input and desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing you need is `.join`:

```
array = [31, 14, 41, 15, 59]

print("[" + ", ".join([
    '{:02x}'.format(x)
    for x in array])
+ "]")
```

Output:

```
[1f, 0e, 29, 0f, 3b]
```

You can also leave out the `[]` from the list comprehension in this case, creating a *generator expression*:

```
print("[" + ", ".join(
    '{:02x}'.format(x)
    for x in array)
+ "]")
```

Comment: Ah, that is indeed nicer. Thx.

Comment: Minor improvement: omit the `[]` inside the `join()`

Comment: @JiříBaum I mentioned that

Comment: I think I was looking at an earlier version of your answer which didn't have the second option yet